# startVPNTunnel on NETunnelProviderManager iOS 9

Tags: ios9, ios-app-extension, networkextension

Since the release of iOS 9 beta, Apple open NetworkExtension.framework which let developers to implement custom protocol VPN client on device.

When I tried to connect a customized VPN with following code

```
    let providerProtocol = NETunnelProviderProtocol()
    providerProtocol.serverAddress = "example.com"

    let manager = NETunnelProviderManager()
    manager.protocolConfiguration = providerProtocol
    manager.enabled = true
    manager.saveToPreferencesWithCompletionHandler({ error in
        guard error == nil else {
            print("saveToPreferencesWithCompletionHandler \(error)")
            return
        }

        do {
            try manager.connection.startVPNTunnel()
        } catch {
            print("startVPNTunnel \(error)")
        }
    })
```

It will failed with `startVPNTunnel Error Domain=NEVPNErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"`

Comment: Were you able to solve this error,I do face the same issue

Answer (score 2):

You must call `loadFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler` before start VPN.

Comment: this is exactly how i fix my issue. when your app redirected you to the system prefs - save changed occurs. So if you load prefs one more time - you updated app vpn config and VPN should started properly

Answer (score 2):

I think before you startVPNTunnel you need to loadFromPreferences like this:

```
manager.saveToPreferences(completionHandler: { (error) -> Void in
                if error != nil{
                }
                else{
                    manager.loadFromPreferences(completionHandler: { (error) -> Void in
                        if error != nil{
                        }
                        else{
                            do{
                                try manager.connection.startVPNTunnel(options: nil)
                            }
                            catch{
                            }
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your configuration is invalid.  Among other things, the protocol has to be configured with the bundle identifier of the VPN plugin you want to load.

I would strongly suggest grabbing some sample code as a starting point.  Configuring one of these beasts is a pretty complex task, and there are a lot of sharp edges where a tiny mistake can cause it to fail completely without any obvious hint about why it failed.

Answer (score 0):

According to document provided by Apple the error code corresponds to NEVPNErrorConfigurationInvalid which is thrown under below scenario

"The VPN configuration associated with the NEVPNManager object is invalid. This error can occur when trying to save the configuration while the configuration has missing or invalid configuration properties, or when trying to use the configuration before it has been successfully saved to the Network Extension preferences or before it has been successfully loaded from the Network Extension preferences"

Fill all properties of providerProtocol and manager and save them.That should fix your problem if not assign the configuration to manager and save them inside manager.loadFromPreferencesWithCompletionHandler method.